# What does return number && number do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a code that returns number && number in javascript.
I have tried to write in the console return num1 && num2 and it has always returned num2.

Answer (score 1):

If `num1` is "falsy" (false, undefined, zero, or null, or an empty string), you'll get the value of `num1`. Otherwise you'll get the value of `num2`.

This is because (like in many other computer languages) `&&` is what's called a "short-circuit" boolean. If the first operand is falsy the second operand doesn't matter for a logical AND operation, so it isn't evaluated.

If the first operand is "truthy", evaluation continues to the second operand, and the result is the value of that second operand.

Unlike many other languages, JavaScript boolean operators don't necessarily yield boolean values. Non-boolean operands can be used to get non-boolean results.

Answer (score 1):

The && operator is commonly called logical and. It can also be called guard. If the first operand is false, null, undefined, "" (the empty string), or the number 0 then it returns the first operand. Otherwise, it returns the second operand.

read it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND